# getting more details about Node.js ECONNRESET error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am running node.js code that someone else wrote. The part in question is below:

```
 client.query('CREATE TABLE ABC (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, stuff VARCHAR(255),  more INT(3))',

        function (error) {
            //Handle an error if it's not a table already exists error
            if(error && error.number != 1050) {
                throw (error);
            }
    });
```

Every time I run it, I get this error:

```
progfile.js:251
                throw (error);
                       ^
Error: connect ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:776:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:767:19)
```

From what i understand, that error means that the database closed the connection?
How do I confirm that, and where can I look to get more information? I need help tracking down why it is happening and how to prevent it from happening.

The Node.js code is running on a WinXP machine, and the database is on a CentOS VPS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node js ECONNRESET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is likely to be somewhere else in your code, and its effects are simply showing up in the code you showed.

In particular, make sure you aren't "falling through" to something that closes your connection before the callback has a chance to run. In your example all that your callback does is check for errors, which makes me suspicious that you're trying to do more things with the database in the code that follows your call to `client.query`. That's not going to work because of the asynchronous nature of the MySQL client; any statements after the call you showed are going to be executed *before* the actual database query has had a chance to run. Anything that relies on your query having been executed has to go *inside* the callback.

If that doesn't make the problem immediately obvious, edit your question to include the code immediately before and after the code you showed.